# bat script to unzip .gz file in a location and extract to another location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to know how to write bat script to unzip file in a location and save the extracted file to a different location, also I need to delete the original file after the extraction is done.

For example suppose my .gz file are in location `C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\` and I need to extract all the files in this location to `C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract`(destination).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved using [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), combined with `forfiles`, something like (not tested, don't kill me if it doesn't work immediately):

```
forfiles /M *.gz /C "cmd /c 7z x @path -oC:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract *.* -r"
```

Where:

```
x   means "extract"
-o  means "output directory"
*.* means "filename inside can be anything, extract every file"
-r  means "recursive subdirectories"
```

Deleting the zipfile afterwards is obvious.

Comment: I specified the source path also, but it doesn't work.Please advise anything is wrong.I am new to this shell scripting.
forfiles /M *.gz /C "cmd /c 7z x @path -o C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract\*.gz -r"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10), version 1803+, (December 2017 to April 2018 - *minimum 10.0.17063*), then you may be better advised to use the built-in [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) executable:

```batch-file
@If Exist "C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\*.gz" (
    If Not Exist "%__AppDir__%tar.exe" Exit /B 1
    PushD "C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR"
    If Not Exist "CDR_Extract\" MD "CDR_Extract" 2>NUL || Exit /B 1
    For %%G In (*.gz) Do @("%__AppDir__%tar.exe" -xf "%%G" -C "CDR_Extract"
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del "%%G")
    PopD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without need to install third party software  - you can use [**gzipjs.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/gzipJS.bat):

```
md "C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract\" >nul 2>&1
for %%# in ("C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\*.gz") do (
  call gzipjs.bat -u "%%~f#" "C:\Users\jibin\Desktop\CDR\CDR_Extract\%%~n#"
  rem del "%%~f#" /q /f
)
```

Check if this is what you need and delete the `rem` word in the last file in order to activate deletion of the source files as you requested.

If you are using windows 10 with all the latest updates (from build `17063` and above) you can use [TAR](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409).